# L2 regularization for the fully connected parameters in CNN

Tags: optimization, tensorflow, loss

In [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py#L236) example for tensorflow, it used L2 regularization for the fully connected parameters.:

```
regularizers = (tf.nn.l2_loss(fc1_weights) + tf.nn.l2_loss(fc1_biases) +
                  tf.nn.l2_loss(fc2_weights) + tf.nn.l2_loss(fc2_biases))
```

what is it? why fully connected parameters used here? and how it improve the prformance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regularizers in general are terms added to the loss function that prevent the model from over-fitting the training data. They do this by encouraging certain properties on the learned model.

L2 regularization of the parameters, for instance, encourages **all** the parameters to be small, instead of being *peaky*. This in turn would encourage the network to pay equal attention to all dimensions of the input vector.

The Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) is a great introduction to regularization in general, and you click through to learn in depth about L2 regularization in particular.

Comment: why fully connected parameters used here?

Comment: We usually regularize the fully connected layers more because they have much more parameters than the convolutions and then tend to overfit more